# Using open source model olama with mixtral

Tags: nlp

I am getting error
ValueError: Ollama call failed with status code 400. Details: invalid options: tools

I am using frame work called as crewai ,it was working fine with gpt4 , but i am getting error ,can someone please explain me this error I think mixtral , openchat are not fine tune for function calling

Comment: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and the full error message

Comment: I'm having the same error trying to use an Ollama model to create a Langchain AgentExecutor using the create_openai_tools_agent method

Comment: @FabrizioCacicia i think the problem lies here these models are not fine tunned for function calling ,I think you need to change the model to that can function calling like nexusravene which are fine tunned for function calling

Comment: @ZaidSiddiqui I knew the issue was the one you pointed out, but I didn't know what model I could use to call functions apart from the OpenAI one, I was looking for a model with this capability. Thanks for pointing out nexusraven. I am going to try it right now.

Comment: @حمزةنبيل thanks  for asking but I think the problem here is some ollama models are not fine tunned for function calling,Need to change to more capable model that can do function calling like of nexusraven

Comment: @FabrizioCacicia do let me know how did it worked for you I think it should solve the problem